# Can I backup chromebook admin control?

Tags: backup, chromebook

I want to back up my Chromebook and was just curious will it also backup admin control so when I return the backup after a wipe it will return admin control as well?

Answer (score 1):

Admin control is tied to the hardware itself and not affected by wiping or anything else you do.